# ListView with grouping is not showing any items

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

In my WP8.1 (WinRT) app, i have a listview control with grouping defined with data binding. But when i run the app i don't see any data items or any binding errors.

I couldn't able to figure out what is the error. Here is my XAML and code, and also how to extend this to jumplists?

my xaml

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="26"  Margin="12,-12,12,6"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}"  Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Language}" Foreground="Orange" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeader">
        <Border Background="Transparent">
            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1"  
                    Width="400" Height="90" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
                           FontSize="28"
                           Padding="2"                                
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>

<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <testApp:DemoViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ListView x:Name="CitiesList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding CityByCountry}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}" />
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and my c# (Model, ViewModel)

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
    public List<KeyedList<string, City>> CityByCountry { get; set; }
}

public class KeyedList<TKey, TItem> : List<TItem>
{
    public TKey Key { protected set; get; }

    public KeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items): base(items)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping): base(grouping)
    {
        Key = grouping.Key;
    }
}
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

i am using below code to load the demodata for testing in main page

```
       List<City> source = new List<City>
        {
            new City {Name = "Madrid", Country = "ES", Language = "Spanish"},
            new City {Name = "Barcelona", Country = "ES", Language = "Spanish"},
            new City {Name = "Mallorca", Country = "ES", Language = "Spanish"},
            new City {Name = "Las Vegas", Country = "US", Language = "English"},
            new City {Name = "Dalas", Country = "US", Language = "English"},
            new City {Name = "New York", Country = "US", Language = "English"},
            new City {Name = "London", Country = "UK", Language = "English"},
            new City {Name = "Mexico", Country = "MX", Language = "Spanish"},
            new City {Name = "Milan", Country = "IT", Language = "Italian"},
            new City {Name = "Roma", Country = "IT", Language = "Italian"},
            new City {Name = "Paris", Country = "FR", Language = "French"}
        };

        // this.citiesList.ItemsSource = source;
        DemoViewModel viewModel = new DemoViewModel();
        var tmp = from city in source
                  group city by city.Country into c
                  orderby c.Key
                  select new KeyedList<string, City>(c.Key, c);

        viewModel.CityByCountry = new List<KeyedList<string, City>>(tmp);
        DataContext = viewModel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use CollectionViewSource to group. Hope this helps you [Jumplists in Windows Phone 8.1 (Updated)](http://modernography.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/jumplists-in-windows-phone-8-1/)

and set your tmp as Source